# Form submission not working

Tags: php, forms, email, contact-form

I have a problem with the Form I'm trying to create. Basically, it does not allow me to send the email to the recipient, even though the PHP code is correct. Few people from SO already tried to help, but it seems the code is not working.

```
<?php
$error = false;
$sent = false;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
        $error = true;
    } 
    else {

        $to = "linardsberzins@gmail.com";

        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);

        $subject = "Contact Form";

        $message =  "Name: $name \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $comments";
        $headers = "From:" . $name;
        $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if($mailsent) {
            $sent = true;
        }
   }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<?php if($error == true){ ?>
  <p class="error">Text</p>
<?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
  <p class="sent">Text</p>
<?php } ?>  
<div id="form">
<form name="contact" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <h4>Contact Me!</h4>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
            <label for="email"/>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
            <label for="comments" id="comments">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id=""></textarea>
            <fieldset>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit"  class="submit" value="Send   email"/>
            <input class="btn" type="reset" value="Reset"/>            
            </fieldset> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Form Submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158229/php-form-submit)

Comment: well, im not getting any errror actually

Comment: `mail()` works fine on my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not rely on `submit` button as not all browsers send that button as a `POST`, change to other input:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
```

Comment: sorry, accidentally pressed the button

Comment: not yet, am at work now, everything is disabled, will do after and let youknow, cheers

Comment: what about `if (isset($_POST))` ?

Comment: `isset($_POST)` is always true so you can't rely on that

Comment: hi, did not work with `if(isset($_POST['name']))` im very confused now, seems to be working fine for other people. Thanks anyway