# PHP form is not submittimg

Tags: php, forms

I have the following form codes, which doesn't submit, when i click the submit button. It gives error report "Something went wrong". I had debugged several times but can't seems to know why. Please, can somebody help me fix this? Thank you very much for the assistance

```
<?php
  $errorMSG = "";

  if (empty($_POST["name"])) 
  {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) 
  {
    $errorMSG = "Email is required ";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) 
  {
    $errorMSG = "Phone is required ";
  } 
   else 
  {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["select"])) 
  {
    $errorMSG = "Select is required ";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $select = $_POST["select"];
  }

  if (empty($_POST["terms"])) 
   {
    $errorMSG = "Terms is required ";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $terms = $_POST["terms"];
  }

  $EmailTo = "fredsoftsolutions@gmail.com";
  $Subject = "New meeting request from Fredsoft Solutions";

  // prepare email body text
  $Body = "";
  $Body .= "Name: ";
  $Body .= $name;
  $Body .= "\n";
  $Body .= "Email: ";
  $Body .= $email;
  $Body .= "\n";
  $Body .= "Phone: ";
  $Body .= $phone;
  $Body .= "\n";
  $Body .= "Package: ";
  $Body .= $select;
  $Body .= "\n";
  $Body .= "Terms: ";
  $Body .= $terms;
  $Body .= "\n";

  // send email
  $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);
  // redirect to success page
  if ($success && $errorMSG == "")
  {
   echo "success";
  }
  else
  {
    if($errorMSG == "")
  {
        echo "Something went wrong";
    } 
   else 
   {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Thank you very much for the assistance

Comment: _"I had debugged several times"_ - please show your exact debugging efforts.

Comment: ...that,s the given codes above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: There's no real debugging there, you only determine that `$success` is `false`. The linked duplicate lists many potential reasons why it might have failed. Other than that, I'd suggest getting to know the [basics of debugging](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/) and checking the values you receive from the form.

Answer (score 0):

usually in order to send an email, one needs to setup a mail server or incorporate it from an existing one or else there would be no domain to send the email from.

Thus I would recommend you to use PHPMailer class that is available at  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.

here is a snippet.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50; // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz'); // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you also have an HTML form, I guess somthing like this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<label for="name">Name
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</label>
<label for="email">Email
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
</label>
<label for="phone">Phone
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
</label>
<select name="select">
    <option value="the_value_you_want_to_send_1">1st value</option>
    <option value="the_value_you_want_to_send_2">2nd value</option>
    <option value="the_value_you_want_to_send_2">3rd value</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Send" />
</form>
```

As you can see the `action=""` is empty. Thus, when you submit this form, the page will refresh.. This means, **the the submitted values will come to the same page**.
Moreover, it is better to use another name for "select" options, like this for example: `name="select_options"` and not `name="select"`

If you want to send these values to another page, you could also use a form action like this:

```
<form action="send_mail.php" method="POST">
```

Inside this PHP file "send_mail.php" you will have the code you havae posted.. but there are some errors too. You need to have something like this:

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit_form"]) {
    //check your $_POST values here
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
    } 
    else {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $errorMSG = "Email is required ";
    } 
    else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }
    //and so on
    
}
?>
```

Last but not least, if you do not use another PHP file to send those $_POST values, you need to insert the PHP code **above** the HTML code, in order to see the error messages first.
I would suggest to do the validations via Javascript and/or jQuery, before submitting the form, though
About sending an email, you could use PHPmailer like @Ferid Bedru Sherif suggests, but this is another question, that you could find answers
Check this complete exmample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158229/php-form-submit)

It will be herlpful to understand and see how all these works

Comment: Thank you. This solves the issue. The <form action="" method="POST"> line was left unreferenced. That's where i got all wrong.

Comment: You are welcome! if this solved your problem and believe it is answered to your question, please mark this post as anwered to help others too